# How can I iterate over two arrays that share a common property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-oriented-design, entity-component-system

I've been working on a very slim Entity Component System in javascript using Pixi.js on the frontend, and I had a question for you folks
A common pattern is the iterators that you use in systems, for example in Unity you can do:

```
    [ComponentType1, ComponentType2], 
    (c1: ComponentType1, c2: ComponentType2) => {
         // run ops on the components
     })
```

How would you architect that forEach function under the hood, given that you have an array of entities and two arrays containing those component types, needing to call a function and pass in the two components as arguments? Essentially, what is the most optimized way to iterate over entities that have both types of components?

Easy way seems to be iterator over the list of entities and check their component types, but i'm wondering if theres a better way. That approach would look something like this:

```
function forEach<T, K>(components: [c1: T, c2: K], callback: (c1: T, c2: K)=> void) {
    entities.forEach((entity) => { 

        if (entity.hasComponent(c1) && entity.hasComponent(c2)) {

            callback(entity.getComponent(c1), entity.getComponent(c2)

        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question ... could you show your way of solving this?

Comment: Do you mean that c1 and c2 are arrays with the same length, and that c1[0] is related to c2[0], or do you mean you want to do a cross-join of some kind?

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Essentially, say you have two arrays storing a certain type of components for an entity. Then, you also have an array of entities, that store references to those components. Now i want to iterate through all the entities that have both components.

Comment: I edited the question to contain an example

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [mcve], since you haven't given type definitions for `entity` and the libraries you depend on aren't tagged in your question.  If you provide code that works in a standalone IDE (like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)) then we can understand it better and say whether it is reasonable or not.  Otherwise we're just guessing.  My guess is currently "sure, do it that way if it works for you", but I'd be more confident if the code here worked.